# javascript timer fires up on the first key press

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with a timer in it. I'm starting the timer with the keypress event, but i want it to execute only for the first key. I'm using a variable to catch the total keys in an other function which there were pressed and i have something like that: `if(totaAttempts==1)` start the timer, but with this solution the timer starts correctly, but is stomps when a key is pressed again. Any better ideas? 
Thanks in advance

```
function setTime() {
    if (totalAttempts == 1) {
        ++totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
    }
}

function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
    } else {
        return valString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Comment: And how do you call those functions?

Comment: I call the function setTime on a keypress event

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable called (something like) 'started'.

Initially set to 0.

On key press, set it to 1.

Use:

```
if( start == 0){
    ... timer ...
}
```

in place of

```
if (totalAttempts == 1) {
    ... timer ...
}
```

That should do it . . .

Comment: xmmm it does not work. The timer is starting on the first key but it's stopping after one second

Comment: Have you set up the var 'totalseconds' before you start incrementing it ? Outside the setTime() function ?

Comment: yeah, outside the function i set up it. the timer works fine before another key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

create a flag variable, e.g. `var hasRan`. initialise it to `false` and then set it to `true` when you run it. and wrap the inside of the function with an `if(!hasRan) {...`. then set the `hasRan` variable to false on the `keyUp` event.

Edit:

is this what you mean?

```
var hasStarted = false;

element.onkeypress = function() {

    if(!hasStarted) {
        setTimeout(setTime, 1000);
        hasStarted = true;
    }

}

element.onblur = function() {
    hasStarted = false;
}

function setTime() {

    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
    hasStarted = false;

}
function pad(val) {

    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
    } else {
        return valString;
    }

}
```

Comment: i have tried that and the solution was to create multiple timers, one for each letter that i have pressed

Comment: paste the whole codeblock so that I can have the full picture

Comment: unfortunately it creates multiple timers too

Comment: without any more code to look at, there is not a lot to go on here.